# error while executing crystal report

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, crystal-reports

I have created a crystal report to display my monthly sales details, so i created my report and data set SQL connection and all my code is working but when i give my 2 dates it is giving me a error that is:

> "file notfound exception was unhandled " , "Could not load file or
>   assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal
>   Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise
>   XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet1\crdb_adoplus.dll' or one of its dependencies.
>   The system cannot find the file specified."

is this about referencing?

```
try
{
   CRPinvDate rpt = new CRPinvDate();
   //my report.
   SqlConnection myConnection = default(SqlConnection);
   SqlCommand MyCommand = new SqlCommand();
   SqlDataAdapter myDA = new SqlDataAdapter();
   sDate_DS myDS = new sDate_DS();
   //my dataset

   myConnection = new SqlConnection(cs);
   MyCommand.Connection = myConnection;
   MyCommand.CommandText = "select *  from Invoice_Info where Invoice_Date between @Invoice_Date1 and @Invoice_Date2";
   MyCommand.Parameters.Add("@Invoice_Date1", SqlDbType.DateTime, 30, "Invoice_Date").Value = DateFrom.Value.Date;
   MyCommand.Parameters.Add("@Invoice_Date2", SqlDbType.DateTime, 30, "Invoice_Date").Value = DateTo.Value.Date;

   MyCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
   myDA.SelectCommand = MyCommand;
   myDA.Fill(myDS, "Invoice_Info");
   rpt.SetDataSource(myDS);

   crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is about referencing, did you add the correct dll to your references and are you refering to it from this class?

Comment: hope i have added correct dll. but is there any possibility find and re add a dll file?

Comment: Delete dll from List of references, Click Dll one and press Delete button, now Right click references -> Add References -> Browse and find the correct dll, select and press ok, it is now added to your references.

Comment: tried, but still no improvement

Comment: solution found. i just edited my appconfig startup part as folowing  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup

Comment: Nice to hear, you found the solution:)

Answer (score 1):

uninstall Crystal Report 
Download Service pack 7 from http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824

this file http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0_7.exe

before installing crystal report install .net framework 3.5 & 4.0
install downloaded crystal report this will solve your problem

Comment: Thanks all. solution found. i just edited my startup part of appconfig 


      <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup